# In Tiptap Editor, how to access Paste Options

Tags: vuejs3, copy-paste, quasar-framework, tiptap

### I'm using tiptap on a vue3 quasar.

and Here's the problem I'm facing

1. **Whenever I paste data, it's not getting newlines. It's all showing up as a single line.**
2. Moreover, for table tags, it only turns into SPAN tags.
   => I suspect this is caused by tiptap not detecting the table tag - I tried adding all the table extensions and still had the same situation.

### Here's what I tried

```js
function pasteEventHandler(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const text = e.clipboardData.getData('text');
        const lines = text.split(/\r?\n/);
        const html = lines.map(line => `<p>${line}</p>`).join('');
        editor.value.commands.insertContent(html);
        // document.querySelector('.ProseMirror').innerHtml = html;
      }
```

I've registered this function with the paste event of editor-content like this

```js
<editor-content
      @paste="pasteEventHandler"
      :editor="editor"
      class="editor-content"
    />
```

This will add the new content in addition to what is already pasted.

So I found a way to disable paste through [this article](https://github.com/ueberdosis/tiptap/issues/456), but the handlePaste function didn't work.

#### Here's how I used it

```js
const editor = useEditor({
        handlePaste: {
          ...
        },

        ...
}
```

and I tried [paste-rules](https://tiptap.dev/guide/custom-extensions/#paste-rules), but not work

#### I tried like this

```js
const editor = useEditor({
     extensions: [
          Paragraph.extend({
            addPasteRules() {
             console.log('test');
              return [
                markPasteRule({
                  find: pasteRegex,
                  type: this.type,
                }),
              ]
          })

        ...
}
```

This extension felt like it only ran once when the editor was rendered.

I also tried using parseOptions, but that didn't work either.

```
const editor = useEditor({
        parseOptions: {
          preserveWhitespace: 'full',
        },
        ...
);
```

I don't know what else to try, is the only answer to touch ProseMirror's API directly?
If you need to touch it, I'd be grateful if you could tell me how to approach it in tiptap.
I'm having a hard time with this.  Thanks

Comment: Do you want to handle paste events at the editor level? Also when you say new lines are not added on paste, have you copied this data from outside the document or from the document itself?